# namespaced model + postgresql issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

Have a problem with PostgreSQL and a namespaced model that I don't understand.

```
@photos = Profile::Photo.where(:attachable_id => id)
```

This throws an:

```
 !! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: 
  ERROR:  relation "profile_photos" does not exist
 LINE 1: SELECT "profile_photos".* FROM "profile_photos"  WHERE "prof...
                                        ^
 : SELECT "profile_photos".* FROM "profile_photos"  
 WHERE "profile_photos"."attachable_id" = 1>
```

I have a model app/models/profile/photo.rb like:

```
class Profile::Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, PhotoUploader
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true   belongs_to :user,
  :dependent => :destroy   #belongs_to  :profile, :foreign_key =>
  'attachable_id', :dependent => :destroy
```

It says the relation is incorrect, but this worked perfectly before namespacing the model. What did I overlook here?

Comment: What's the name of the table in the db?  You mention it worked perfectly before, you might need to use `set_table_name` if it is not, indeed, `profile_photos`

Comment: It seems my table is renamed to profiles_photos, I thought it had to be multiple with a s not sure now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was incorrect named models, I refactored to correct plural format and renamed the tables correctly which fixed the problem.